# Bulk Exporting Non-Tabular Excel Data into a Database

Tags: sql, excel

We're facing a massive data migration that consists of about 1500 Excel Spreadsheets that were used to print out data.  Because they were designed to be visual, the data is stored in several fields throughout the spreadsheet.   I'm looking for a way to map out those fields, and then do a bulk import to bring all of it into a single large table (or series of tables, if needed).

If it was all in a table format, this wouldn't be a problem - but I'm not sure of any way to import, and somehow map the fields to be imported).

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the data is stored in the EXCEL? Also what is the Target DB and Version?

Answer (score 0):

If we're speaking in generalities, I'd look at performing this task via a .NET program and use the ACE OLEDB provider to query the Excel data. Then use the language of your choice to parse the data into something more manageable and write to the database. This approach worked well to import some very non-tabular data into SQL Server.

Quick list of SO questions with C# examples of code to query Excel.

- [How to query excel file in C# using a detailed query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207693/how-to-query-excel-file-in-c-using-a-detailed-query)
- [OleDB Read Excel decimal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909216/oledb-read-excel-decimal-value)
- [Importing excel files in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003295/importing-excel-files-in-c)